# Is there any Win 10 compatible app to manage screen backgrounds on multiple monitors?

Tags: display

Windows 10's built-in interface to manage screen backgrounds on multiple monitors is poorly designed.

I'm looking for some external alternative, is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DisplayFusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lz43.gif) is your answer.

It has a free and a pro version and I believe either of them would work fine for you as it covers a lot of use case scenarios.

https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Wallpaper/

[image]